# What is the rule for using inversion with "as"?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-inversion

As far as I know, we can use either inversion or normal sentence order with "as" when we are talking about things or people in the "as clause" that are different from those we are mentioning in the independent clause, for example:

"**John and Mary** brought their kids to the party, as **did we** all / as **we all** did."

"**I**'ve often wished **I** could afford to work less, as **do most people** / as **most people do**, I suspect."

But we cannot use normal sentence order when--in spite of talking about different things or people in each clause--the clause with "as" is uttered by a second person. So we have to use inversion, right? For example:

**Jill**: Did you see that **John and Mary** brought their kids to the party?

**Jack**: **As did we all**. What's the point?

Is this rule correct?

By the way, is "as" acting as an adverb of comparison in the above examples?

Comment: relevant: [Inversion after “than”/“as”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162255/inversion-after-than-as?lq=1)

Comment: In conversation, I would say, "As we all did".  For me it would sound slightly pompous to say, "As did we all."  So I disagree with your premise.

Comment: If I was Jack in your example, I wouldn't use "as" at all. It doesn't help answer Jill's *question*. If she'd made a *statement* - "I saw John and Mary," then "As did we all" would be a reaonable reply.

Answer (score 1):

In formal written language we commonly use inversion after **as** and **than** in comparisons:

> Paper was invented in China, **as** was the process of printing.

**Note** that we don't invert subject and verb after as or than when the subject is a pronoun:

> We now know a lot more about the universe **than** we did ten years ago. (not... than did we ten years ago.)

*From Advanced Grammar in Use by Martin Hewings (Unit 99)*